# Related to Compact and Connected set

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, connectedness

Is the following set $S$ compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

$$S= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | xy<0 \}$$

Is the set $S$ connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I've done the compact part by looking the set in $xy$ plane.. Clearly it's not bounded and hence not compact. But how to approach connectedness??
Help me figure it out..

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The considered set is the union of the second and the fourth quadrants. These are quite “clearly” disjoint, so the set is not connected.

Answer (score 1):

It is the union of the disjoint open sets $\{(x,y): x<0, y>0\}$ and $\{(x,y): x>0, y<0\}$. So by definition of connectedness the set is disconnected.

Comment: Thank u so much.  I just remembered that I've studied this criteria of connectedness in metric space.. But on the spot i suddenly forgot it.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It is not connected, because the image of the continuous function $f\colon S\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=x$ is $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, which is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

> A set $S$ is **not connected** if it is equal to the union
>   of two or more disjoint non-empty open sets.

1) In your case, it is easy to show that $S=A \cup B$, where:
$$A\equiv \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x<0\text{ and } y>0\},$$
$$B\equiv \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x>0\text{ and } y<0\}.$$

2) Most importantly, $S=A\cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, non-empty, and open.

- It is easy to see that $A$ and $B$ are non-empty and disjoint.
- Depending on how rigorous you need to be, it may take a *tiny bit of work* to show that they are open.

3) Therefore, $S$ is not a connected set.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try to show that A and B are open sets.

Comment: @user684646 You're welcome! I've been assuming that you are using the Euclidean Topology, which implies the following definition of "open": a set is open if every point in the set can be "wrapped up" in some ball (ball=circle in the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$) which is also strictly contained within the set. You may want to look up the precise definition but this is the direction I would recommend looking at.